# How do I sketch a line from two points (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) in abaqus?

Tags: 3d, line, abaqus

I have two points (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2). I have to sketch a line between these two points in Abaqus. How do I sketch it?

Comment: Do you want to create 1D object (line) in 3D space or do you want just a line using 2 points in the sketcher? Please give enough detail of your problem statement. For ex. why you doing it, what is the error you are facing, what options you tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also included Z coordinates, I assume that you want to create a line in 3D, not in a sketch. In such a case, you can create two reference points and connect them using the wire feature.